# ffmpeg lowpass filter increase roll off

Tags: ffmpeg, lowpass-filter

I have converted one of my old SACD's to 352kHz FLAC, but due to the nature of DSD, a lot of noise is added to the higher frequencies, which are outside the audible range, but consume quite some disk space.

[image: 352kHz FLAC - no lowpass filter]

So I thought I'd use the simple [lowpass](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lowpass) filter to get rid of it, like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.dsf -af "lowpass=26000" output.flac
```

However, the result is that the noise is still there, but only lowered in volume:

[image: 352kHz FLAC - with lowpass applied]

Is there a way to increase the roll-off of the filter or another way to get up to -140 dB at ~48 kHz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL,DR:

Use sox instead:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.dsf -f wav -acodec pcm_s24le pipe:1 | sox -S -t wav --ignore-length - --compression 8 output.flac sinc -32k -t 16k
```

...will get rid of all the high frequency distortion and reduce file size dramatically (bringing it back close to DSD):

- DSD64 (SACD): ~162 MiB
- FLAC (352.8kHz - no filters): ~396 MiB
- FLAC (352.8kHz - lowpass): ~189 MiB

## Long Read

OK, I found out, that one can simple chain the filters and by using slightly different roll-off frequencies. For the following, I simply converted the DSD files without any filter to FLAC (hence, in the following commands we have `input.flac` instead of `input.dsf`).

Using the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af "lowpass=24000,lowpass=28000,lowpass=30000,lowpass=32000" output.flac
```

...resulted in:
[image]

Which looked really nice.

I then checked how close it still was to the original in the lower (audible) frequencies:

```sh
sox -S -m -v 1 input.flac -v -1 output.flac -n spectrogram -x 640 -y 200 -Z -30 -o "lowpass.ffmpeg.diff.png"
```

...result:
[image]

So, no way I can keep that in my library. As I was searching for alternatives, I came across this nice informative read:

- [How to Create a Configurable Filter Using a Kaiser Window](https://tomroelandts.com/articles/how-to-create-a-configurable-filter-using-a-kaiser-window)

So, based on that new information, I fired up sox instead:

```sh
sox -S input.flac --compression 8 output.flac sinc -32k -t 16k
```

...which result in:
[image]

...and confirmed via diff, that audible frequencies remain untouched:
[image]

Comment: Can you please give me more explanation on the `sinc`'s parameters? And what is the `audible frequencies` you said? Below 24kHz or 30kHz?

Comment: @KaneGreen The first parameter "-32k" tells the sinc to do a low-pass filter up to 32kHz (6dB point). The option "-t 16k" tells it to calculate a transition bandwidth of 16kHz around that, so effectively from 24kHz to 40kHz. This means that everything up to 24kHz should be completely untouched.

Comment: So, 32kHz is the center point, and 16kHz is the width around this center point, is that right?